# How to convert text to html character codes with a bash script?

Tags: html, bash, type-conversion

I tried `recode`:

```
echo '>' | recode ascii..html
&gt;
```

But it only seems to convert characters like `>` `<` and `"`:

```
echo 'a' | recode ascii..html
a
```

I want to convert letters and other characters too. I.e, the desired output of the above command is `&#97;`.

Is there any simple way to do this without creating some big regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use printf to get ascii value of characters using ' in front of the variable.  This will of course result in `&#62;` instead of `&gt;`. You can use the code bellow to convert $1 to a string of html ascii codes.

```
str=$1
for (( i=0; i<${#str}; i++ )); do
  c=${str:$i:1}
  printf "&#%d;" "'$c" #
done
echo ""
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      recode
echo '>' | recode ascii..html
&gt;

  ><    "

echo 'a' | recode ascii..html
a












&#62;              &gt;



str=$1
for (( i=0; i<${#str}; i++ )); do
  c=${str:$i:1}
  printf "&#%d;" "'$c" #
done
echo ""
```